# Sum of squares considerations

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

this problem is originally from the number of irreducible representations for a dihedral group, but the context doesn't matter in this case.

The equation $ n-1 = a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \dots + a_{\frac{n}{2}+2}^2 $ where $a_i $ is a positive integer and $n$ is even. What can be said about the coefficients $a_1, a_2 \dots $?

We can set the following criterion, $ 1 \leq a_i \leq \sqrt{n/2 -2}  $. My question is, can we be more precise? The order of the coefficients doesn't matter, but there might be more than one solution.

The same goes for $ n-1 = a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \dots + a_{\frac{n+1}{2}}^2 $ when $n$ is odd. What conclusions can we draw?

Best regards

Comment: Hm. If we set all coefficients to 1 except for one, doesn't that yield the following?

Comment: You are correct, I edited the post. Thanks!